# Display global page object from contentscript to popup in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an object **WIO** on a webpage which i want to access in my **chrome extension**. I have followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) and injected my script.js in the page using first method.

I can successfully read **WIO** object in script.js. But the problem is i can't access it in popup.html.

Any suggestions will be great appreciated.

Here is manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Campaign Analyzer",
  "description": "Analyze campaign data",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

inject.js

```
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
  this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

script.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(WIO.sessionInfo.context);
}, 6000);
```

Comment: The answer in the linked topic should work so I guess you've adapted it incorrectly. Add your code and a proper [MCVE](/mcve) to your question. Or use a different [example](/a/46870005). More info: [here](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm
I have an object **WIO** in the page which i need to access.

I have injected my script.js using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) you linked in the comment. It outputs the WIO object but incorrectly.

Also, if i log WIO.sessionInfo key it return undefined.

Comment: It probably means there are properties inside that page variable that aren't JSON-compatible (string, number, boolean, null, or arrays/objects of these types). Instead of transferring the entire object, only send the select fields you want. Or send JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(WIO))

Comment: JSON parsing and stringify doesn't work either

Comment: I suggested two things but you replied only to one. Anyway, this is as far as guessing can go. The approach itself is correct so now you need to debug it to see what actually happens. For example add console.log for the object inside the script element code.